# run custom sql from php file in magento installation

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am very new to magento and trying to run custom sql queries . But its not runnning . I included all the mage files needed and it gives the error `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context` .

my query file content

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::init();
$setup = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup', 'core_setup');

$installer = $this;


$table = $this->getConnection()
    ->newTable($this->getTable('campaigns/paramcampaign'))
    ->addColumn('entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Campaign ID')
    ->addColumn('campaignname', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Campaign Name')

    ->addColumn('campaigndesc', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, '64k', array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Campaign Description ')

    ->addColumn('campaignnameprice', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DECIMAL, '12,4', array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Campaign Goal Price')

    ->addColumn('campaignstartdate', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME, 255, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Campaign Start date')

    ->addColumn('campaignenddate', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME, 255, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Campaign End date')

    ->addColumn('campaignfbgoal', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        ), 'Campaign Facebook Shares/Likes Goal')

    ->addColumn('campaignpinterestgoal', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        ), 'Campaign Pinterest Shares Goal')

    ->addColumn('campaignamtdonate', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        ), 'Campaign Percentage / Amount To Donate ')

    ->addColumn('campaigncheckpercent', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Is The Specified Amount is Percentage ? ')

    ->addColumn('campaigngoalrecv', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DECIMAL, '12,4', array(
        ), 'Campaign Goal Amount Achieved')

    ->addColumn('campaignfbgoalrecv', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        ), 'Campaign Facebook Shares/Likes Goal Achieved ')

    ->addColumn('campaignpingoalrecv', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        ), 'Campaign Pinterest Shares Achieved ')

    ->addColumn('url_key', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
        ), 'URL key')

    ->addColumn('status', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        ), 'Status')

    ->addColumn('in_rss', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        ), 'In RSS')

    ->addColumn('meta_title', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
        ), 'Meta title')

    ->addColumn('meta_keywords', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, '64k', array(
        ), 'Meta keywords')

    ->addColumn('meta_description', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, '64k', array(
        ), 'Meta description')

    ->addColumn('created_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        ), 'Campaign Creation Time')
    ->addColumn('updated_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        ), 'Campaign Modification Time')
    ->setComment('Campaign Table');
$this->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$table = $this->getConnection()
    ->newTable($this->getTable('campaigns/paramcampaign_store'))
    ->addColumn('paramcampaign_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Campaign ID')
    ->addColumn('store_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Store ID')
    ->addIndex($this->getIdxName('campaigns/paramcampaign_store', array('store_id')), array('store_id'))
    ->addForeignKey($this->getFkName('campaigns/paramcampaign_store', 'paramcampaign_id', 'campaigns/paramcampaign', 'entity_id'), 'paramcampaign_id', $this->getTable('campaigns/paramcampaign'), 'entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->addForeignKey($this->getFkName('campaigns/paramcampaign_store', 'store_id', 'core/store', 'store_id'), 'store_id', $this->getTable('core/store'), 'store_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->setComment('Campaign To Store Linkage Table');
$this->getConnection()->createTable($table);
$table = $this->getConnection()
    ->newTable($this->getTable('campaigns/paramcampaign_product'))
    ->addColumn('rel_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'identity'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Category ID')
    ->addColumn('paramcampaign_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
    ), 'Campaign ID')
    ->addColumn('product_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
    ), 'Product ID')
    ->addColumn('position', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
    ), 'Position')
    ->addIndex($this->getIdxName('campaigns/paramcampaign_product', array('product_id')), array('product_id'))
    ->addForeignKey($this->getFkName('campaigns/paramcampaign_product', 'paramcampaign_id', 'campaigns/paramcampaign', 'entity_id'), 'paramcampaign_id', $this->getTable('campaigns/paramcampaign'), 'entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->addForeignKey($this->getFkName('campaigns/paramcampaign_product', 'product_id', 'catalog/product', 'entity_id'),  'product_id', $this->getTable('catalog/product'), 'entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->setComment('Campaign to Product Linkage Table');
$this->getConnection()->createTable($table);
$this->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//ini_set("display_errors",1);

require_once 'app/Mage.php';

Mage::init();

Mage::app("default");

$installer= Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup', 'core_setup');

//$installer = $installer;

$installer->startSetup();

$table = $installer->getConnection('core/resource')
->newTable('tablename')
->addColumn('entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'identity'  => true,
    'nullable'  => false,
    'primary'   => true,
    ), 'Campaign ID')
->addColumn('campaignname', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Campaign Name')

->addColumn('campaigndesc', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, '64k', array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Campaign Description ')

->addColumn('campaignnameprice', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DECIMAL, '12,4', array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Campaign Goal Price')

->addColumn('campaignstartdate', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME, 255, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Campaign Start date')

->addColumn('campaignenddate', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME, 255, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Campaign End date')

->addColumn('campaignfbgoal', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    'unsigned'  => true,
    ), 'Campaign Facebook Shares/Likes Goal')

->addColumn('campaignpinterestgoal', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    'unsigned'  => true,
    ), 'Campaign Pinterest Shares Goal')

->addColumn('campaignamtdonate', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    'unsigned'  => true,
    ), 'Campaign Percentage / Amount To Donate ')

->addColumn('campaigncheckpercent', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Is The Specified Amount is Percentage ? ')

->addColumn('campaigngoalrecv', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DECIMAL, '12,4', array(
    ), 'Campaign Goal Amount Achieved')

->addColumn('campaignfbgoalrecv', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'unsigned'  => true,
    ), 'Campaign Facebook Shares/Likes Goal Achieved ')

->addColumn('campaignpingoalrecv', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'unsigned'  => true,
    ), 'Campaign Pinterest Shares Achieved ')

->addColumn('url_key', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
    ), 'URL key')

->addColumn('status', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    ), 'Status')

->addColumn('in_rss', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    ), 'In RSS')

->addColumn('meta_title', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
    ), 'Meta title')

->addColumn('meta_keywords', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, '64k', array(
    ), 'Meta keywords')

->addColumn('meta_description', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, '64k', array(
    ), 'Meta description')

->addColumn('created_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
    ), 'Campaign Creation Time')
->addColumn('updated_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
    ), 'Campaign Modification Time')
->setComment('Campaign Table');
 $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

 $installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: please post comments if you run into further errors

Comment: I thing is i made a extention using magento extention creator . i copied the files and still it does not runs . i found that no database tables were created . only this file does that . i am trying to run this file anyhow so that my database tables are created and i get a relief its really being over 25 hours i am stuck at this

Comment: are you executing this on your modules sql files?

Comment: this is not running when i try to install that module . and this file is the only thing left . i am trying to run this as a standalone .

Comment: I tried it on my local server with a few changes,I think it can work for you

Comment: what changes . Can you please suggest me ? This has been a nightmare really

Comment: It worked for me I've updated my answer, How I tried

Comment: I've updated my answer,I took part of your code and executed it. and I'm able to create the table in my database. Please let me know if you run into further issues

Comment: Thank you till whatever code you wrote it worked . i can see the database table . i used the following after wards it gave me error ` ->newTable('paramcampaign_store') ` when i tried using it in second `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Can't retrieve entity config: campaigns/paramcampaign_store`

Comment: about that you cannot use "$this->getTable('campaigns/paramcampaign_store')" on stand alone php files
give your table names. Do not do it magento way here my advice

Comment: wait ill tell . i guess i can figure this out

Comment: Well finally i was able to create the tables . Thank you so much for your help but the plugin didnt showed up . Not a part of this question . So anyways thank you . I think i need to drop this idea